# .jspf not compiling even though in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-fragments

I have two files. `choose.jsp` and `little.jspf`

**choose.jsp**

```
<c:import url="little.jspf">
    <c:param name="his" value="${param.choice}"></c:param>
</c:import>
```

**little.jspf**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<br />
this is little.jsp <br />
I just heard that somebody here said ${param.his} is important.
```

**Output**

output is `I just heard that somebody here said ${param.his} is important.`
But when I change the .jspf to .jsp it compiles fine. Is it not possible to pass parameter to .jspf file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .jspf file is supposed to be statically included (with the `<%@include %>` directive) inside another JSP. Not dynamically included or imported.

I would create a [JSP tag file](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html) instead of using `c:import`.

Comment: would it be wrong to just rename my .jspf file with .jsp ? seems like a simpler solution... (looks like JSP tag files are in the next chapter of my book)

Comment: It's OK. Just not as elegant as a tag file. Why not read the next chapter of your book?

Comment: Will do, just have to do some examples and clear everything before moving on, or i forget.